# Wix Installer Registry Search Fails

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am attemping to do a registry search with in a wix installer so that I know where to install my plug in. I am trying to look up where Tekla Structures 2018i is installed at. However, every time I try running the installer my condition fails. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Product tag:

```
<Property Id="TSMAINDIR">
        <RegistrySearch Id="TS2018iSetupMain"
                        Root="HKLM"
                        Key="Software\Tekla\Structures\2018i\setup"
                        Name="MainDir"
                        Type="raw"
                        Win64="yes"/>
      </Property>
      <Condition Message="This application requires Tekla Structures 2018i. Please install Tekla Structures 2018i then run this installer again.">
        <![CDATA[Installed or TSMAINDIR]]>
      </Condition>
```

RegEdit:
[image]

### UPDATE:

I have created a log file. The file is rather lengthly so I will not post it. However, When I do a search for TSMAINDIR I find the following:

```
AppSearch: Property: TSMAINDIR, Signature: TS2018iSetupMain
MSI (c) (00:34) [14:25:26:994]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Signature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (00:34) [14:25:26:994]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding TSMAINDIR property. Its value is 'C:\Program Files\Tekla Structures\'.

MSI (s) (E4:2C) [14:25:27:694]: Ignoring disallowed property TSMAINDIR
```

Comment: You can try the Secure attribute as I have added to the answer below first of all, and then we will see if that by chance solves the problem. I doubt it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks OK to me. You have the right bitness flag so you search the x64 section of the registry. Have you looked in the log file? [How to create a log file](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msifaq/a/1022.htm).

I don't really think it should matter since you are not in deferred mode, but try setting the property to be secure:

```
<Property Id="TSMAINDIR" Secure="yes">
<...etc...>
```