# Wix RegistrySearch

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have installed wix as a plugin in Visual studio. I am trying to search for if MATLAB Version 9.2 exists on the PC then allow installation or else abort. To achieve this I do like this

```
<Property Id="MATLABRUNTIMEEXISTS">
  <RegistrySearch Id="Matlab_runtime_search" 
                  Root="HKLM" 
                  Key="SOFTWARE\MathWorks\MATLAB Runtime\9.2" 
                  Name =" MATLABROOT"
                  Win64="yes"
                  Type="raw"/>
</Property>
<Condition Message="This application requires RUNTIME 9.2. Please install the Matlab runtime 9.2 then run this installer again.">
  <![CDATA[Installed OR MATLABRUNTIMEEXISTS]]>
</Condition>
```

It works fine, and installer is halted when there is no MATLAB on PC. But even after installing MATLAB it stops the installer.

The `MATLABROOT` key is "REG_SZ" and "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime".

So what I want to test is actually only the presence of `MATLABROOT` key.

I saw in other questions people are using `<util:RegistrySearch>`, but I am not able to use that. I receive error "unsupported extension element", even though I have `UtilExtension` as reference already added.

Could anyone suggest me what I need to do to actually make it work?

Comment: Do you build your setup for 32-bit or 64-bit? If it's 32-bit, you need to set `Win64="yes"` for `RegistrySearch`.

Comment: I am building for 64-bit. I have tried Win64="yes" also. But it didn't help either.

Comment: Is the leading whitespace in `" MATLABROOT"` intentional?

Comment: Maybe show us a screen shot of this registry key and values?

Comment: [Please check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52744148/wix-installer-registry-search-fails). [Another answer you can check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56030940/129130).